# Xamarin, Android, RecyclerView: Smooth background downloading of objects and then setting them

Tags: c#, android

In our app, we constantly reload objects from the server and then place them inside a recyclerview scrollview. Now, it does work fine but it is a big laggy. Like - it scrolls, then stops and reloads for a second, then scrolls, then reloads and so on and so forth. I have noticed that other apps do this differently. For instance, when one scrolls thorugh facebook. One can scroll all the way down and then, when the images have done loading, they get placed inside their empty layout container. So I thought this is only achievable via background threadding - so I have done that but the result is the above mentioned. It is just nowhere near as smooth as it is with facebook or any other app where you scroll throuh images. What could be the problem here:

```
    private async Task LoadTHEBOOKAsync(PVH_TheBook_Singles vh, int position, int fkTaskId)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Loading on another Thread
            int taskID = loadPhotos.pictures[position - (this.hasHeader ? 1 : 0)].taskID;
            int taskIDWHenTheBook = loadPhotos.pictures[position - (this.hasHeader ? 1 : 0)].fullscreenID;
            Bitmap bmp = loadImage(position);
            String commentCount = KumulosHelper.Functions.Pictures.GetCountOfComments
                                    (fkTaskId.ToString()).ToString();
            String LikeCount = loadPhotos.pictures[position - (this.hasHeader ? 1 : 0)].likes.ToString();
            int taskDoneId = loadPhotos.pictures[position - (this.hasHeader ? 1 : 0)].taskdoneid;
            String exp = null;

            if (taskID != 0)
            {
                exp = BookOfLife.Challenges.Libary.Instance.getTask(taskID).Experience.ToString() + "ap";
            }
            else
            {
                exp = BookOfLife.Challenges.Libary.Instance.getTask(taskIDWHenTheBook).Experience.ToString() + "ap";
            }

            // Setting on UI Thread
            ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                vh.Image.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
                vh.txtComments.Text = commentCount;
                vh.txtLikeCountBlue.Text = LikeCount;
                vh.taskdoneid = taskDoneId;
                vh.txtap.Text = exp;                                   
            });
        });

    }
```

As you can see, all the donwloading is done in an async task and only the placing is done on the ui thread. Is this wrong? Because I cannot seem to find any other solution to this ? I mean, I do have to set my images on the UI thread, right? So i HAVE to block it for a second until everything sits right, dont I?

Any help would be awesome.
Thanks! :)

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: does something similar exist in xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [WoWonder Android Timeline](https://codecanyon.net/item/mobile-native-timeline-applications-for-wowonder-social-php-script/19703216) which is built in xamarin and you get more info there about the news feed system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV4sm.jpg)